# jQuery -> Selected Element to HTML

Tags: jquery

I am trying to wrap specific elements in a box if the visitor is using < IE9 so I can apply a box shadow across all browsers.

Unfortunately I cannot quite work out how to do it. Does anyone know how to convert the selected element back into HTML?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').each(function() {
            var img = $(this).clone();
            var html = '<div class="bounding">'+$(img)+'</div>';
            $(this).replaceWith(html);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The script is printing out `[object Object]`. `.html()` doesn't work because that is basically innerHTML. Is there a jQuery function that achieves this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [.wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$('img').wrap('<div class="bounding" />');
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/BTJmn/

Comment: Looks like we all had the same idea, so +1 for being first!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').wrap('<div class="bounding" />');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The great news is that the guys at jQuery thought of this situation and created [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

You use it like this:

```
$('img').wrap('<div class="bounding" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jQuery function [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').wrap('<div class="bounding" />');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to wrap an existing element in some other element. There is a convenience method for that in jQuery: [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

So, your code would look like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').wrap('<div class="bounding" />');
});
</script>
```